# Jar building doesn't work in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I'm very new to Gradle and I have the project structure like this:

```
Project Name
   src
     package1 
       .java
     package2
       .java
```

My gradle build looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

version = 0.1
sourceCompatibility = 1.6

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/*'
        }
    }
}
```

And when I run `gradle jar` the jar is been created. But looking the jar, it has only the `MANIFEST` folder, not the compiled classes.

Where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`srcDir` doesn't accept wildcards. (Where did you get this from?) Try `srcDirs = ['src']`. (This will override the default directory, rather than adding another one.)

Comment: Thanks that works. How do I say the depedency libs too?

Answer (score 1):

When you are new to gradle I'd advice you to use the standards (convention over configuration) part - so put your Java sources in src/main/java - and you do not need the sourceSets part.

If you want to use it, check http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/java_plugin.html